# Using @input property in child component to call service in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Communication data from parent component to child component using @input in angular 2. My purpose is I want to call service in child component using value parameter @input, but the value property is "undefine". this is my child component :

```
import { Component, OnInit,  EventEmitter, Input,Output } from     '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child', 
    templateUrl: './child.component.html'
})

export class ChildComponent  implements OnInit {


    @Input() productId: any; --> working perfectly if bind into html

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.productId) --> undefine?
    //in this methode i will call service to fetch another data from database using parameter productId..


    }
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Why do you think it should be defined? Where does `productId` come from?

Comment: from parent component, your answer is perfect @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: If you fetch it from a server then it's not yet available when `ngOnInit()` is called. A setter or `ngOnChanges` also works for data that is set later. `ngOnInit()` only works for data that is already available when the component is created.

Comment: thank you very much @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 4):

I would use a getter and setter and inside the setter, you would make your service call.

```
// Declare a private underlying variable for the getter and setter
private _productId: any;
@Input()
set productId(id: any){
    this._productId = id;
    // Make your service call here
}
get productId(){
    return this._productId;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear! If this solves your issue, could you please mark the answer as accepted? Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either ngOnChanges or ngAfterViewInit:

```
export class ChildComponent  implements OnChanges {
    // Subscribe to the change event and update the model
    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
        let key = 'Data';
        this.productId = changes[key].currentValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Input() 
set productId(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: This is sufficient if all you need is to perform an action inside the setter and if you do not actually use the productId anywhere else. But if you need to access this variable, then you need to implement a getter as well and have a "backing field".